# Random Member Access in C

Tags: c

Suppose a struct like:

```
struct node{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
    struct node* next;
}
```

And a function which iterates through a singly linked list with a tmp pointer;

```
void getMember(char* member_name){
    While(tmp != NULL){

    //here, I'd like to access a user defined member passed into the function
    // something like printf("%d\t", tmp[member_name]);

       tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
```

I tried using pointer arithmetic to access it via an offset, like:

```
//suppose member_name is instead an offset of size, like sizeof(int), rather than the char* shown above;
printf("%d\t",*(&(tmp)+member_name);
```

But the arithmetic isn't guaranteed in a struct like it is an array because of padding. Aside from turning on packing, which I think would make the arithmetic work, how would one implement random access to members of a struct in C? Can it be achieved with this sort of data structure? Or is using something else necessary?

Comment: You might want to look at `__builtin_offsetof`. But in general, accessing random user-specified properties are a problem. If they can be of multiple types, then you also need to pass in a constant that you map to the type in question. If they're all of the same type... that sounds like an array, and an index should be all you need.

Comment: @Siguza why look at __bultin_offsetof instead of offsetof which is in the C standard?

Comment: @Shawn Referring to previous comments (which I have upvoted), it seems you simply need to get `sizeof tmp->field` plus `sizeof tmp->field1` and add all fields before the one you wish to access. If you wanted to automate this, you should create a list of integers specifying the size of each element, then run a sigma function on that array until you have reached the desired field

Comment: `a` and `b` are `int`, but `c` is `char`. Does it even make sense to pick one of those members at run time? Setting that aside, if you need random access, why aren't they elements of an array? Or if you really need to access them by name as a string, you'll need some data structure that maps strings to integers (a hash table, for example). Other languages, including C++, have better built-in support for this kind of thing. If they need to be struct members, you could use `offsetof()` to find their offsets and build a table.

Comment: And consider whether you might have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).